# Translating the title of a custom block

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I am using the Bluemaster theme on a Drupal 7 site. I want to translate my site and everything is OK, but the title of the block I adde is not translated and still shows as "User menu" even when the language is not English.

[image: screenshot]

How can I change the block title so that it appears in the language set for the site?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
in '/admin/structure/block' find your block, click on `configure` link beside it  then in `Language setting tab` Check "Make this block's title translatable"
Then Go to Translate interface admin/config/regional/translate/translate
Then enter the block title above and limit search to "block"

Comment: @Sumit Aggarwal If this answer solved your problem, it would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to activate the module "Block Language" for this steps (from @[Val Budkin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/916/val-budkin)) to work.